# How to increment a Customizer add-control ids using button type in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to ask for help, I am currently learning the WordPress customizer and iplementing it on my project. I have a select field which I would like to increment and decrement on button click (+/-).

```
$wp_customize->add_section('samplecustom_section' , array(
 'title'      => esc_html__('Sample Customizer', 'theme_name'),
 'priority'   => 169,
 'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
)); 

$wp_customize->add_setting('sample-list', array(
  'default'           => '',
  'transport'         => 'refresh',
));

 $wp_customize->add_control('sample-list', array(
  'label'       => esc_html__('Sample Label', 'theme_name'),
  'description' => esc_html__('Sample description', 'theme_name'),
  'section'     => 'samplecustom_section',
  'settings'    => 'sample-list',
  'type'        => 'select',
  'choices' => array(
    'value1' => __( 'Value 1' ),
    'value2' => __( 'Value 2' ),
    'value3' => __( 'Value 3' ),
 ));

 // button
 $wp_customize->add_control('add_button', array(
  'section'     => 'samplecustom_section',
  'settings'    => 'sample-list',
  'type'        => 'button',
  'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
  'input_attrs' => array(
  'value'     => '+',
  'class'     => 'customizerbutton button-primary',
  )
 ));
```

here is a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27YkR.png) where when I click the plus button the select field will increment (or decrement by minus button) creating new ids for the add-control customizer.

Comment: What happens now when you click the button?

Comment: nothing happens